# Entry in sudoers

Tags: sudo

I need the following entry for a autoresponder/vacation plugin for roundcube with plesk:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /opt/psa/bin/autoresponder
```

But the system doesn't recognize www-data as a user. Only the "www" of www-data.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my server and I tried it on several machines.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Hi, for sure it is www-data. I have changed it above.

Comment: I have the same problem and not found solution for it. please.